# How to download zipfile on Linux?

Tags: linux, wget

I want to download a file from this website :
https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/ZGOUED

```
   Access datasets   >>> download Zip
```

I copied the address and tried:

```
 wget https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/ZGOUED#
```

But did not work

Answer (score 4):

The URL which you passed to `wget` as an argument is the same as the URL of the page. So, you got the page itself instead of the file. Judging from the `#` at the end of the URL, you copied it by right-clicking the download menu at the page. But it is not a direct link to the file. When you click there, the javascript at the site generates the download link for you. The link is different for each download. You can test it yourself by downloading it multiple times from multiple browsers and see the download history in the browser for the download link. It is done intentionally to prevent automated downloads. I don't think you really wish to bypass it.